# Definite Clause Grammars, differences between SWI-Prolog 7 and older

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

It does work on SWI-Prolog 4

```
letter(X) --> [C], {"a"=<C, C=<"z", name(X,[C])}.
```

And in SWI-Prolog 7 the following is working

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
letter(X) --> [C], {"a"=<C, C=<"z", name(X,[C])}.
```

Searching in SWI-Prolog website I found:

```
Mode--------------double_quotes-----------back_quotes
Version 7 default-----string------------------codes
--traditional----------codes--------------symbol_char
```

So why

```
letter(X) --> [C], {`a`=<C, C=<`z`, name(X,[C])}.
```

doesn't work?

Comment: SWI 7 has destroyed compatibility with earlier versions. You can use `--traditional` to get rudimentary ISO compliance. Also, I recommend `chars` instead of `codes` for *much* nicer output in all versions and also in other Prolog systems.

Comment: Better replace `name(X,[C])` by `char_code(X,C)` - that's better everywhere

Answer (score 0):

just to simplify the context, let's test an equivalent expression (a goal conjunction)

```
?- C=0'd, `a` =< C, C =< `z`.
C = 100.
```

seems it's working...

```
?- [user].
letter(X) --> [C], {`a`=<C, C=<`z`, name(X,[C])}.
|: ^Dtrue.

?- phrase(letter(X), `d`).
X = d.
```